# Re-scaling technique

Tags: statistics, gamma-distribution

I am trying to re-scale this integrand to prove that it is the density function of a Gamma distribution:

$$\int^∞_0 \frac{(αθ^α)\cdot λe^{-αλ}}{x^{α+1}} \, d\alpha$$

I pulled out $λ/x$ to get:

$$\frac λ x \int^∞_0 α \left(\frac\theta x\right)^\alpha e^{-\lambda\alpha} \, d\alpha$$

From here I am unsure how to re-scale this to become a Gamma. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac \lambda x \int^\infty_0 \alpha \left(\frac\theta x\right)^\alpha e^{-\lambda\alpha} \, d\alpha = {} & \frac \lambda x \int_0^\infty \alpha \left( \frac \theta x e^{-\lambda} \right)^\alpha \, d\alpha \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac \lambda x \int_0^\infty \alpha \left( e^{-\lambda\log(\theta/x)} \right)^\alpha \, d\alpha \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac \lambda x \int_0^\infty \alpha e^{-\beta\alpha} \,d\alpha \\
& \text{where } \beta = \lambda\log(\theta/x) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac \lambda {x\beta^2} \int_0^\infty (\beta\alpha) e^{-\beta\alpha} (\beta\, d\alpha) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac \lambda {x\beta^2} \int_0^\infty u^{2-1} e^{-u} \, du \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac \lambda {x\beta^2} \Gamma(2).
\end{align}
Then change $\beta$ back to what it is.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Just one question, how did you go from the second to last step to the last? (as in how did you get gamma(2) from the integral of u^(2-1)e^(-u) du ?)

Comment: @uytt : The most frequently seen characterization of the Gamma function, often taken to be the definition, is this: $$ \Gamma(a) = \int_0^\infty x^{a-1} e^{-x} \,dx. $$